# Using Custom HttpHandler for Clickonce Authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

I was tasked with finding a way to control access to a ClickOnce link, using Forms authentication.

A quick Google search led me to [this article: Make ClickOnce Work With ASP.NET Forms Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24519/Make-ClickOnce-Work-With-ASP-NET-Forms-Authenticat).
After trying to implement this complex process, I realized that if a wrote a simple IHttpHandler to process all ClickOnce file types, (such as *.application, .deploy*,) I could then easily check if the current user is authenticated or not.

So my handler would be:

```
public class ClickOnceApplicationHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point for the handler, here we determine if we have an authenticated user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        var _path = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.Path).ToLower();
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && System.IO.File.Exists(_path))
        {
            if (_path.EndsWith(".application") || _path.EndsWith(".fuple"))
            {
               //do the stuff I need to here if user is authenticated.
               //redirect to the myapp.appication

            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see how an unauthorized user can get past here?